# Neo4j: Get Min/Max of multiple node/relationship properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How is it possible to find the min/max of multiple node/relationship properties?

I prepared the following graph: https://console.neo4j.org/r/3ehhme.

Its basically (U:User)-[i:invests]->(P:Project).

1) i has the property: amount:1000

2) U has the property: availableAmount:500

I need the smaller value of 1) property of i and 2) property of U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a scaler function for this, the `min()` and `max()` functions you get from Cypher are aggregation functions that work across rows, which isn't what you need here.

If you have [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/overview/) installed you can make use of `apoc.coll.min()` and `apoc.coll.max()` which work across elements of a list:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[i:invests]->(P:Project)
RETURN U, apoc.coll.min([i.amount, P.availableAmount]) as minValue
```

If you don't have APOC or aren't allowed to use it, then you can use the CASE structure to find the minimum:

```
MATCH (U:User)-[i:invests]->(P:Project)
RETURN U, CASE WHEN i.amount < P.availableAmount THEN i.amount ELSE P.availableAmount END as minValue
```